# I can´t find my mistake with this compareTo(T) function in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, comparable

I´m learning Java at School right now and im learning (heredity/inheritance?).
I already used it in C# but i have the Problem, that my compareTo-method is wrong so i keep getting the error "Class 'Fraction' must either be declared abstract or implement abtract method 'compareTo(T)' in 'Comparable'.

I understand from the Documentation that the "T" is for the datatype its supposed to compare, is that correct?
If yes, what is my mistake?

I got the same errror with "Number" but it worked fine there.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Fraction extends Number implements Comparable <Fraction>
{
    BigInteger[] RationaleZahl = new BigInteger[2];    


    public static void main(String [] args)
    {

    }

    public int CompareTo (Fraction Bruch)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    public double doubleValue(double d)
    {
        return d;
    }

    public float floatValue(float f)
    {
        return f;
    }

    public int intValue(int i)
    {
        return i;
    }

    public long longValue(long l)
    {
        return l;
    }
}
```

Comment: compareTo method name starts with smaller case

Comment: in C## Methods are usually written with first uppercase, in Java they start with lowercase - but most important, Java is also case sensitive! To override a method cases must match! And, despite not needed, the use of `@Override` (the line before declaring the method) is indicated to get a warning when the method is not overriding/implementing as expected

Comment: Thank you guys, sorry for the stupid mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You have created a method

```
 public int CompareTo (Fraction Bruch)
```

Change this to

```
 public int compareTo (Fraction Bruch)
```

And you are good ...

Answer (score 0):

You capitalized `CompareTo`, so it doesn't match `compareTo`